# How to create a SpreadSheet kind of display in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to display a SpreadSheet in the Android application with auot adjustable columns and each columns should surrounded by lines.I used the Table Layout the data are displayed in the Table format but i dont know how to surround each column with lines, auto adjustment.If anyone knows it please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TableLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.LayoutParams.html) or [TableRow.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html). They inherit [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html), which you seem to need.

A sample code with TableRow.LayoutParams could be:

```
// you can also init values for width, height and weight here
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
params.setMargins(LEFT_MARGIN, TOP_MARGIN, RIGHT_MARGIN, BOTTOM_MARGIN);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("I'm in the table");

TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.addView(textView, params);
```

The same principle could be applied with TableLayout.LayoutParams, when you add to the table layout.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a background color for the `TableLayout` and give your `TableRow`s a margin:

```
<TableLayout android:background="#000000">
    <TableRow android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="3dip">
    <!-- etc. -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply,it will be useful while using XML,but i am adding TableRows through java code for dynamic layout purpose.you have any idea in java code

Comment: You may use the `View`'s `setBackgroundColor` and `MarginLayoutParams.setMargins` to achieve the same in code.

Answer (score 4):

I open-sourced an elementary spreadsheet I wrote here:

https://github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet

One elementary features it does not have yet:

You can load Microsoft Excel pre-2007 (.xls) files, but not Excel 2007/2010 (.xlsx) files.  This is the feature I have been stuck on implementing for a while.  There is a codebase (POI) out there to do this, but there are complexities to implementing it.

Comment: can you give your jar including your app,i download some jar,but some method is mistake

Comment: I managed to run the app and it looks real excel. Greate job. But as soon as cursor out of visible range, the app crashes. I wouldn't really worry about xlsx but I wonder how you would deal with excel data with limited gridview.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this article with a **Spreadsheet layout** example. Maybe it can be helpful to someone too. But it is just an example, still need to update it for general purpose.

http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html