# How to open an Excel file using JXL in android

Tags: android, excel

I want to open an Excel file from an SDCARD on an Android phone. Which API should I use?

Comment: thanks,...But Sir, I want to Open Excel sheet in Android Phone Display. so, How it Possible in Android ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use an API such as [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

I have no experience with this API but apparently you can [use it with Android](http://www.kylebeal.com/2011/10/using-jexcelapi-in-an-android-app/).

Comment: its ok..but not read excel file ..actully i want to open excel file..for example like in computer excel file open in ms office same thing i want open excel file in android front page looking like in pc so, which tool or API use ??Thanks in Adavance

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll still want to use the [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) to read the contents of the file. As far as displaying the data on an Android device you'll probably want to look at [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355860/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-kind-of-display-in-android) is an answer outlining TableLayout to create a spreadsheet type display. This could also be done by reading the Excel file contents into HTML and displaying the HTML in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)