# User interface and selective sync in google drive / google spreadsheet

Tags: android, excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Hi I am new to android development and planning to develop a spreadsheet application, which should allow the user to

1) Create and edit a spreadsheet file in local device
2) Have file level control to allow/disallow syncing with google drive. Google credentials could be asked *only* if the user is interested in syncing.

My questions are:
1)  Does google Drive/ Google spreadsheet provide any APIs for user interfaces? What will be the best way to implement the user interface?

2) Is selective syncing possible using google drive / google spreadsheet API?

Comment: Do you want to create a spreadsheet editor? Or sync data with a spreadsheet. i.e. what will your user interface do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two spreadsheet api are: google-apps-script and google-spreadsheet-api ...

Google apps script has good docs and is of good quality, but I suspect google-spreadsheet-api
 will be a better fit for android development, but depends on your needs.

The google CellDemo.java demo gives a good overview of the spreadsheet api. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

There is also ethercalc - it is a web based spreadsheet, good quality, all open source.

Comment: Thank you Eddy - I tried the code out and it works well for working with files in google drive programmatically! However it does not seem like the google spreadsheet API provides a user interface to be easily added to my app. Is this correct? Do I have to implement an UI from scratch (table layout, etc)? That would mean I have to implement several of the basic functions (e.g. sorting of cells) myself - correct?

Comment: @user3268403 as I asked above, what will your user interface do? A table with sorting/editing/live calculations?  ... Both APIs only deal with data, they don't create a UI, you need something else for that. But there are open source java UIs around with spreadsheet like functionality.

Comment: Eddy, appreciate your response and thanks for helping me out. You are absolutely right, the UI is a table for sorting, editing, etc. I have been looking at some java UIs as well (e.g. openXLS, JExcel). Which ones do you recommend? Also, looks like java UIs cannot be directly displayed in android - they have to be converted into android layouts, views, etc. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You might be better to ask a new question. I don't know what options exist for building your own spreadsheet UI on Android. I assume you don't want to use an existing App.

Comment: I do not want to use an existing app. I will ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Google providing API for this. Kindly check this [google developers link](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.in/2014/01/introducing-google-drive-android-api.html) for more information. I hope you are familiar with designing of spreadsheet like layout and all in your app. If that thing is achieved, you can do it this also by putting small effort.

Comment: Aneez, should the spreadsheet like layout be achieved using basic android components or is there a better way to do this? Could you point me towards a tutorial/code? I am unable to find a good one

Comment: You can use list view feature. Create a custom list view with columns you want. Then add the rows dynamically. Or kindly go through this [Question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355860/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-kind-of-display-in-android) .