# Ways to present a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

**I am creating a layout which contains a Dynamic table of rows and columns, created on button click.**

**Details:**

This is working well, now I want is that while I added new columns- from a menu the list must be show. which contains some names for the header of table.

further on selecting any one name the table column should be added that header with same name.

**What I want:**

The idea how to display it like adding space in the layout or in the context menu or something else a good way.

I hope someone can suggest me some links or some suggestion or some idea or anything for this.

[image]

Thanks.

Note: There is two menu option on first one columns will increase and on 2nd one rows will increase. It may be some times the screen could be filled up with table.

**Check this calender View in this image.**

[image]

Comment: Can you include any wireframe, screenshot so we better understand what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: ok i am adding it

Comment: I added the ui image

Comment: cells with blue background are headers and I wish to generate a list for this.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355860/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-kind-of-display-in-android)

Comment: This part is done. I want to add list of items now just you can assume as context view that appears. How can I achieve it

Comment: check another image for what sort of result i want

Comment: Add a click listener to the view you want to show the menu while generating the view itself. Than show a dialog or popup or whatever when listener is triggered